# How to convert a column vector into a diagonal matrix with same entries in same order?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Assume $c$ is a column vector. What mathematical operation or expression can produce a diagonal matrix with entries of that of $c$ in same order. Does such an expression exist?

Basically I know that the sum of entries of $c$ is zero. I want to write it in an matrix expression/equation. I am hoping if I get a diagonal matrix and then say trace of that matrix is zero.

Comment: Any better alternative is also fine.

Answer (score 3):

The usual notation used for this kind of thing is as follows: if $c = (c_1,\dots,c_n)$ (a column-vector in your case), then we say
$$
\operatorname{diag}(c) = \pmatrix{c_1 \\&\ddots \\&& c_n}
$$
where the blank entries are zeros.

Answer (score 2):

Let $K$ be a field. Then define the mapping $T:K^n \to K^{n \times n}$ by

$$ T((c_1,c_2,...,c_n)^T)= diag (c_1,c_2,...,c_n).$$

Answer (score 2):

One standard way is to let $e=(1,\ldots,1)^T$ be the all-ones column vector of the same length and then write $e^Tc=0$.

Answer (score 1):

Transformation can be made with the use of standard basis vectors $e_i$ which are columns of identity matrix.

Then 
$\text{diag}(c_1,\dots, c_n)= (e_1^Tc)e_1e_1^T+ \dots +(e_n^Tc)e_ne_n^T$.

Comment: Expression $(e_1^Tc)$ should be here treated as a scalar, in fact it can be treated as a scalar product, as this thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2167231/how-does-the-dot-product-convert-a-matrix-into-a-scalar shows, more exactly we could write it   as $\text{tr}(e_1^Tc)$