# Matrix geometric interpretation

Tags: linear-algebra

What is the geometric interpretation of a matrix with only one element? If it means One dimension then how to identify the dimension viz X,YorZ?

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer just a share of thought or discussion.

In general,the concept of matrix is related to linear transformations from some dimensional space to some dimensional space and in case of a $1 \times 1$ matrix, we must have a linear transformation from a One-dimensional space to one-dimensional space. The way you want the dimension i.e. X,Y or Z is not defined in 1-D space. It has only one dimension.

Comment: Thanks for replying...My Query is if we can represent the 2*2 matrix using column vectors. How are we going to represent 1*1 matrix geometrically?

Comment: did you mean this: Let, $A_{1\times 1}=(a)_{1\times 1}$ then $A_{1\times 1}=a\bullet (1)_{1\times 1}$, $a$ is a scalar quantity.

Comment: Actually I got to know that the numbers used in the matrix are actually the multiple of unit vectors that shows that a 1*1 matrix is a vector and not a scalar.

Comment: check this out : https://www.quora.com/Is-a-1-x-1-matrix-a-scalar

Answer (score 1):

A $1 \times 1$ matrix is a number.  To represent a number, all you need is a [number line](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Number_line). If you prefer, you can think of this number line as an "$x$-axis".

If you represent a $2 \times 2$ matrix with $2$-dimensional "column vectors", then the analogous representation of a $1 \times 1$ matrix would be an arrow on the number line, pointing from zero. That is, we can represent numbers as vectors on our $x$-axis.

Comment: My [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076174/81360) regarding $1 \times 1$ matrices also comes to mind.

Comment: Thanks for replying...So the Vectors concerned are the Unit vectors .