# Determinant of identity plus the sum of two outer products in $\{-1,1\}^d$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $a > 0$, $d \in \mathbb{N}$ and define
$$
 A= I_d + a(v_1 v_1^T + v_2v_2^T)
$$
where $I_d$ is the $d$-dimensional identity matrix and $v_1, v_2 \in \{-1, 1\}^d$. What is the determinant of $A$? I wanted to use something like the [Matrix Determinant lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_determinant_lemma) but is is not entirely clear to me how this works when we add two vectors. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The matrix determinant lemma applies when we add a rank-1 matrix. When we add a matrix of arbitrary rank (that is low relative to the size of the matrix), then the applicable generalization is the [Weinstein–Aronszajn identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinstein%E2%80%93Aronszajn_identity) (AKA the Sylvester identity). In particular, we can write $a v_1v_1^T + av_2v_2^T$ as $aVV^T$, where $V$ is the matrix whose columns are $v_1,v_2$. With that, we have
$$
\det(I_d + aVV^T) = \det(I_2 + V^T(aV)) 
\\= \det \left[I_2 + a\pmatrix{v_1^Tv_1 & v_1^Tv_2\\v_2^Tv_1 & v_2^Tv_2} \right]
\\= \det 
\pmatrix{ad + 1 &  v_1^Tv_2 \\ v_1^Tv_2 & ad + 1}\\
= (ad+1)^2 - a^2(v_1^Tv_2)^2\\
= [d^2-(v_1^Tv_2)^2]a^2 + (2d)a + d^2.
$$

Comment: In this context [I'd advise](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2899919/56861) writing $v_i\cdot v_j$ instead of $v_i^Tv_j$, but +1 for an excellent approach.

Comment: @J.G. I [disagree](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076174/81360)