# A question on multiplying matrices by scalars

Tags: linear-algebra

The the product of two matrices AB is defined if and only if the number of columns *n* in A equals the number of rows *m* in B. But what if A is a 1x1 matrix (i.e. a scalar) and B is some *m* x *n* matrix where *m* > 1?

Comment: [A $1 \times 1$ matrix is not a scalar.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/65002/are-one-by-one-matrices-equivalent-to-scalars)

Comment: You'll tire yourself out with questions like that.  The easy answer is "*don't sweat the small details.*"  Imagine scalars as not being matrices at all (*even if they could be interpreted as matrices*) and make a distinction in your mind between $1\times 1$ matrices and scalars.  Be aware that you can freely swap between interpretations as is convenient to you for ease of writing.  This is like how we might think of the number $1$ as the natural number, as the integer, as the rational number, as the real number, etc... depending on context, and freely switch between which we are referring to

Comment: Matrix multiplication and scalar multiplication are not the same operations.

Comment: See also [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2076174/81360)

Comment: Thank you all for your comments (+1), these all help to answer my question.